# Swing: How do i create an east hugging component that will not move over western components

Tags: java, swing, docking

I've tried several ways to get this to render correctly.  I want my logo area to hug east as the window is resized, but not to overlap the Western components.  The following code does not hug east, which i think makes sense because the the logoArea box does not know it should take up the rest of the horizontal space.

If i add the logoArea directly to the 'area' then it hugs east, but will overlap the western components if the window shrinks too much.  Any ideas?

```
 Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
 box.add( main );
 for( JComponent item : items ) //western stuff
 {
    box.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut( 8 ) );
    box.add( item );
 }

 //eastern stuff
 Box logoArea= Box.createHorizontalBox();
 logoArea.add( new JLabel( LAF.Icon.png( "CompanyLogo" ) ), BorderLayout.EAST );

 box.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut( 8 ) );
 box.add( logoArea, BorderLayout.EAST );

 JPanel area = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
 area.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 2, 2, 2, 2 ) );
 area.add( box, BorderLayout.WEST );
 return area;  //dashboard is built
```

**EDIT**

To answer @Nitin i'd like it to move left until it reaches the western components, and then stop moving and disapear from the right side.

Comment: Have the container use BorderLayout, and place the component into it in the BorderLayout.LINE_END position.

Comment: What behaviour is expected when the window shrinks more than that to accommodate the components?

Comment: @Hovercraft:  this approach exibits the same behavior as my second approach, "If i add the logoArea directly to the 'area' then it hugs east, but will overlap the western components if the window shrinks too much"

Comment: Would `JSplitPane` be suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know any standart layout that would act as you want, but its not hard to create one. Check this small example (cross-shaped paintings displays content and logo bounds):

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

    LogoLayout layout = new LogoLayout ();
    frame.setLayout ( layout );

    frame.add ( new JLabel ( "Label with same preferred size as text length" )
    {
        protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
        {
            super.paintComponent ( g );

            g.setColor ( Color.BLACK );
            g.drawLine ( 0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight () );
            g.drawLine ( getWidth (), 0, 0, getHeight () );
        }
    }, layout.CONTENT );

    frame.add ( new JComponent ()
    {
        protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
        {
            g.setColor ( Color.BLACK );
            g.drawLine ( 0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight () );
            g.drawLine ( getWidth (), 0, 0, getHeight () );
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
        {
            return new Dimension ( 100, 100 );
        }
    }, layout.LOGO );

    frame.setSize ( 700, 500 );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack ();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setVisible ( true );
}

public static class LogoLayout implements LayoutManager
{
    public String CONTENT = "Content";
    public String LOGO = "Logo";

    private Map<Component, String> constraints = new HashMap<Component, String> ();

    public void addLayoutComponent ( String name, Component comp )
    {
        constraints.put ( comp, name );
    }

    public void removeLayoutComponent ( Component comp )
    {
        constraints.remove ( comp );
    }

    public void layoutContainer ( Container parent )
    {
        Insets bi = parent.getInsets ();
        int contentSize = 0;
        int logoSize = 0;
        int maxHeight = 0;
        for ( Component component : parent.getComponents () )
        {
            Dimension ps = component.getPreferredSize ();
            if ( constraints.get ( component ).equals ( CONTENT ) )
            {
                contentSize = Math.max ( ps.width, contentSize );
            }
            else if ( constraints.get ( component ).equals ( LOGO ) )
            {
                logoSize = Math.max ( ps.width, logoSize );
            }
            maxHeight = Math.max ( ps.height, maxHeight );
        }

        int width = parent.getWidth () - bi.left - bi.right;
        int height = parent.getHeight () - bi.top - bi.bottom;
        for ( Component component : parent.getComponents () )
        {
            if ( constraints.get ( component ).equals ( CONTENT ) )
            {
                if ( contentSize + logoSize < width )
                {
                    component.setBounds ( bi.left, bi.top, width - logoSize, height );
                }
                else
                {
                    component.setBounds ( bi.left, bi.top, contentSize, height );
                }
            }
            else if ( constraints.get ( component ).equals ( LOGO ) )
            {
                if ( contentSize + logoSize < width )
                {
                    component
                            .setBounds ( bi.left + width - logoSize, bi.top, logoSize, height );
                }
                else
                {
                    int scaledLogoSize = width - contentSize;
                    if ( scaledLogoSize > 0 )
                    {
                        component.setBounds ( bi.left + width - scaledLogoSize, bi.top,
                                scaledLogoSize, height );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize ( Container parent )
    {
        Insets bi = parent.getInsets ();
        int contentSize = 0;
        int logoSize = 0;
        int maxHeight = 0;
        for ( Component component : parent.getComponents () )
        {
            Dimension ps = component.getPreferredSize ();
            if ( constraints.get ( component ).equals ( CONTENT ) )
            {
                contentSize = Math.max ( ps.width, contentSize );
            }
            else if ( constraints.get ( component ).equals ( LOGO ) )
            {
                logoSize = Math.max ( ps.width, logoSize );
            }
            maxHeight = Math.max ( ps.height, maxHeight );
        }
        return new Dimension ( bi.left + contentSize + logoSize + bi.right,
                bi.top + maxHeight + bi.bottom );
    }

    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize ( Container parent )
    {
        return preferredLayoutSize ( parent );
    }
}
```

Is that how you want your LOGO to act when window is getting sized?

P.S. This way you can also modify the layout anytime you need to add (for example) another specific component location, some gap between logo and content or anything else...